Confused by nulls in terminal
So I'm practising kdb with some self-imposed challenges. This one is a program supposed to tell you if it's someone's birthday today. (I just used letters instead of names in this version).
My question is this: what are those three nulls that the terminal outputs?


.aaa.bdic: `a`b`c!((01 12);(02 01);(29 04))

.aaa.bdic
a| 1  12
b| 2  1 
c| 29 4 

  {if[((`dd $ .z.P)=.aaa.bdic[x][0]) and (`mm $ .z.P)=.aaa.bdic[x][1]; show "it's " , (string x) , "'s birthday!"]}each key .aaa.bdic

"it's c's birthday!"
::
::
::

I tried adding another item to my dictionary and I got four nulls instead of three.
A simpler function returns a similar weird output:

show each .aaa.bdic
1 12
2 1
29 4
a| ::
b| ::
c| ::


Those nulls :: just indicate your function gives no output, or rather than the output is null ::. You see 3 because there are 3 keys and you run the function 3 times.

Your function uses an if statement which does not intentionally return a result, but a q function always returns a resulting object and (::) is the generic null which is used in this cases.
You use each on a three element dictionary. Calling each on a dictionary places the output of the function to the left of the each as the values in the resulting dictionary.
You can add ; to the end of your statement if you do not want the returned value to be outputted.
q){if[((`dd $ .z.P)=.aaa.bdic[x][0]) and (`mm $ .z.P)=.aaa.bdic[x][1]; 
        show "it's " , (string x) , "'s birthday!"]}each key .aaa.bdic;
"it's c's birthday!"

Each-left \: and each-right /: are example of https://code.kx.com/q/ref/iterators/
-1 prints to standard output https://code.kx.com/q/basics/handles/
q){-1"It's " ,string[x], "'s birthday!"} each where all each (`dd`mm$\:.z.P)=/:.aaa.bdic;
It's c's birthday!

